# Best approach for ordering emails in C# 4.0 for maximum delay and preventing possible false spam alarm

Tags: c#, wpf, email, c#-4.0

I will send all of my registered players a very important announcement mail. Now i want to order all of the emails in my database. This order will be like

```
first@hotmail.com
first@gmail.com
first@yahoo.com
first@mymail.com
```

then the second row starts

```
second@hotmail.com
second@gmail.com
second@yahoo.com
second@mymail.com
```

**The aim of order is to send an email to a domain with the maximum possible delay. (sending an email to @domain1, @domain2,...  @domain99, @domain1, @domain2, repeat. I will make the order 1 time only so the time it is going to take is not important. I have got like 320k emails.**

I want to do this with c# 4.0 wpf application. What would be the best possible approach. You can assume that every email has id. It would make ordering easier.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Are you trying to order how they look in the header, or are you sending out 320 thousand separate emails?  That many emails sounds dubious to me.

Comment: When I was reading the question, it sounds like the OP wants to send 320K individual emails, and have as long a time as possible between sending another to the same domain so spam filters do not grab the messages.

Comment: Adam Wenger you understood correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach, but it requires that you store an extra `mailorder` field with each user record.

Go through each of the user records and add it's id to a list of lists where each of the sublists consists of email address for a particular host. So you'll have one list for `gmail.com`, one for `yahoo.com`, etc.

Calculate the length of the "shortest" list longer than some reasonable minimum such that no list has more than 2 or 3 times the number of items in this short list.  For each list calculate the number of addresses per round to take from this list by using the ceiling of the length of the list divided by the length of the "shortest" list.  It should be no less than 1.  Call this *itemCount<sub>i</sub>* for list `i`.

Set `mailOrder` to 0.

Go through the list of lists, extracting the first *itemCount<sub>i</sub>* ids from each list `i` and update the `mailorder` field for the corresponding records with the value of the `mailOrder` variable.  Increment `mailOrder` by one and repeat until all lists are exhausted.

When you send emails, sort the user records by the `mailorder` column (be nice to have an index on this to make it snappy).  Periodically rerun the algorithm to account for new users, who could be given a temporary `mailorder` of one more than the maximum `mailorder`.

An alternative, perhaps better, approach would be to take a fixed maximum number of emails per list per round until the list is exhausted and send a single email to all of the addresses for a particular host (using Bcc, probably) at once in each round.  This will help minimize the number of emails that you actually send.  Choose the number of addresses per round based on what you can safely send to that mail host without tripping over its limits.

Comment: your idea give me a very good idea. first of all i will extract all of the extensions (email provider) . after that i will assign each extension to a unique id. after that i will save all of the emails to a table with their extension. then in a while loop of extensions i will select 1 row from database with that order extension and send email. with this way i will be sending each company email after send all other companies :)

Answer (score 2):

This will sort your your email addresses assuming the variable email here is an `IEnumerable<string>.`

```
email
    .OrderBy(e => e.Split(new char[] { '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ElementAt(0))
    .ThenBy(e => e.Split(new char[] { '@' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ElementAt(1));
```

However, depending on how many combinations of emails and domains, you are likely still going to iterate over this resulting set too fast for the email hosts not to freak out, so you probably will also want to add some delay to to your processing loop.

Comment: I agree about needing to add a delay to not upset the email providers.

Comment: i will add delay but instead of sending an email to the same email provider consequently i can send others  and then send again so it would even increase the delay.